# had predicted or predict?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, present-tense

Does the past perfect in the following passage have a past event as
its anchor point?

> To be a good scientist, you have to be tolerant and patient when
>   experiments or interpretations do not turn out as you **had predicted**.
>   You must be able to stand high levels of frustration.

Also consider the following. Should "predict" or "had predicted" be used?

> Sometimes, things do not turn out the way you **predict**/**had predicted**.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, yes, there is an event which is anchoring the *past perfect* verb in that sentence, but it is not a past event.  The use of the *past perfect* there is indicating that the prediction happened/happens before the results of the experiment "turn out".  This is a hypothetical event rather than a past event, but the *past perfect* works the same way for both.

For your second question, you can actually use either form of the verb.  If you use the *past perfect*, then the implication is pretty much exactly the same as in your first sentence:

> Sometimes, things do not turn out the way you had predicted.

This is, again, a hypothetical case, so the use of *past perfect* is anchored to "whenever things turn out", and it implies the prediction will have happened some time before that, whenever it might be.

> Sometimes, things do not turn out the way you predict.

This is because, again, it's a hypothetical situation, and in hypotheticals the present tense does not mean *right now*, but rather means *at some arbitrary point in time*.  As a result of this, even though the two verbs here are both using *present* tense, they do not necessarily have to happen at the same time, they can each have their own (different) points in time:

> Sometimes, (at some point in time) things do not turn out the way you (at some other point in time) predict.

Since predictions generally come before results, this implies that the prediction will happen before "things turn out", even if it doesn't explicitly say it.

Comment: Thank you. If both "predict" and "had predicted" refer to hypothetical situations, there seems to be little, if any, difference, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, in these sorts of constructions there's no real difference in meaning.  The only difference, really, is "had predicted" feels a bit more like it's talking about one specific case, while "predict" feels more like it's talking about all cases in general.